# How to create menu and submenu with adf navigation pane

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm trying to create a complete menu with submenus using adf navigation pane. I already have an unbounded adf task flow and its adf menu model is correctily generated.

But navigation pane only generates first navigation level but no lower. exist any way to implement a menu and submenu using adf navigation pane?

Comment: Did you try the tutorials online: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_43/jdtut_11r2_43.html 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24382_01/web.1112/e16181/af_navigate.htm

Comment: Sure, I'm familiar with most adf faces components. I partially solved by implementing tree component with #{root_menu} as value but there are another issue, it's rendered collapsed even when initiallyExpanded attribute is set to true. I have changed scope from request to session but links nullpointerexception is thown. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create multiple instances of Navigation Pane and change the **level** Attribute to view the sub menu of the first level, and second level etc...

Comment: Well the documentation isn't clear so having an example in your answer would have benefit the 4K viewers.

Comment: @MrAdibou this is a very old question, a fully explained example (with pictures) is explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_43/jdtut_11r2_43.html